# How do I find whether an entry in a list is larger than the next 50 numbers of that list, without using for-loops?

Tags: python, list, vectorization

I have a very long list of continuous data. For each list entry, I want to know whether it is larger than the next 50 entries to come. Since it is a lot of data, it needs to be efficient, but I don't come much further than this:

```
 list = [5,3,7,4,7,12,6,3,2,1,6 .... 5] # n = >80.000.000
 new_list = list()

 for i,val in enumerate(list):
    if val > max(list[i:i+50]):
      new_list.append(1)

    else:
      new_list.append(0)
```

Can some help me vectorize this problem? Or some suggestions how to go from here?

Comment: Which language are you using ? I can give you an answer in js, purescript, haskell or Php

Comment: If you order your list in a descending order, that condition always holds

Comment: I use Python @Hangover Sound Sound

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use PySpark.

If this method cannot be applied, multiprocessing is applied.

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed


def func(data, index):
    return True if data[index] > max(data[index : index + 50]) else False

src = [5,3,7,4,7,12,6,3,2,1,6,5,5,3,7,4,7,12,6,3,2,1,6,5,5,3,7,4,7,12,6,3,2,1,6,5,5,3,7,4,7,12,6,3,2,1,6,5,5,3,7,4,7,12,6,3,2,1,6,5]
dst = Parallel(n_jobs=-1, backend="threading", verbose=10, max_nbytes=None)(
    delayed(func)(src, index) for index, value in enumerate(src)
)

print(dst)
```